# Rootview controller is not working with tabbar controller Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, rootviewcontroller

Im having login pages where im trying to push each ViewController and after successful verification im trying to set root view using code

```
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Some") as! Some
```

Above code is not working and for logout also im setting the root view controller, but those are not working. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

`Login 1st page(navigationController.pushVc)`--> `Success Verification (setting root view controller)` --> `Logout(setting root view controller)`.

I have given identifiers to both tabbar controller and navigation controller. Tried in many ways but could not find solution

Tried this link also https://fluffy.es/how-to-transition-from-login-screen-to-tab-bar-controller/

Above link is the same which im trying.But can't do in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I am copying my method here to switch rootViewController after login and logout. I have written this method in AppDelegate:

```
public func setRootVC(){
    
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Strings.LOGGED_IN) != nil {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let tabbarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ViewControllerIdentifiers.TabbarController)
        
        self.window?.rootViewController = tabbarVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    else{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let loginNavController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ViewControllerIdentifiers.LoginNavController) as? UINavigationController
        
        self.window?.rootViewController = loginNavController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Calling this method from my viewController:

```
@IBAction func signoutBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Strings.LOGGED_IN) != nil {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: Strings.LOGGED_IN)
    }
    self.appDelegate.setRootVC()
}
```

To access 'self.appDelegate I have added this extension in my viewController

```
extension UIViewController {
var appDelegate: AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```

}